# jQuery prevent change from firing when SelectList is updated with new values

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events, selectlist

I have a `SelectList` that has a change event attached to it. When the user selects a new option, it updates that list via a `getJSON` method (as well as other `SelectList`s). However, when the list is updated, jQuery sees that as a change and keeps firing in an infinite loop (changing, updating, repeat).

Is there another event I can use or something that can prevent the change event from firing when `getJSON` is called on the list?

Comment: Can you please provide some code snippets

Answer (score 0):

Just from the information you provided, it seems like you have a few options.

1) Use the jQuery `one()` method instead of `on()` that way you can add the listener back once you are ready to start listening for changes again.

2) You can remove the callback to prevent it from firing right before your `getJSON()` call. Then in your callback after the json response gets back, reattach the change listener to your select element. This is very similar to the above approach, but might be more work.

3) You can also disable the select element until the `getJSON()` callback is invoked. This in your change listener, if it gets fired while the select element is disabled, you can first check if it's disabled before running your logic.

If you post more code, then I can give you a more tailored answer. Let me know if that helps.